# Como realizar login usando Requests?

Tags: python, login, autenticação, python-requests

Estou tentando extrair os dados de um site usando pela primeira vez o `requests`, mas sempre que eu tento extrair os dados, mesmo adicionando login e a senha, ele extrai os dados da página de login como se ele não consegui-se avançar com o login, acredito que o motivo é porque a tela de login está usando *popup*.

Fiz esse mesmo código em dois sites diferentes e funcionou. Somente este que deu esse problema.

```
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with Session() as s:
    site = s.get("https://shopper.com.br")
    bs_content = bs(site.content, "html.parser")
    login_data = {"email":"xxxxx","senha":"xxxxx"}
    s.post("https://shopper.com.br",login_data)
    home_page = s.get("https://programada.shopper.com.br/shop/alimentos/acucar-e-adocantes/")
    print(home_page.content)
```

Explicando o código:

```
    site = s.get("https://shopper.com.br")
    bs_content = bs(site.content, "html.parser")
```

pega a página onde deve ser feito o login.

```
    login_data = {"email":"xxxxx","senha":"xxxxx"}
    s.post("https://shopper.com.br",login_data)
```

cria um dicionário dos parâmetros a serem usados ​​para o login. As chaves dos dicionários são os atributos de NAME das tags de entrada.

```
    s.post("https://shopper.com.br",login_data)
    home_page = s.get("https://programada.shopper.com.br/shop/alimentos/acucar-e-adocantes/")
    print(home_page.content)
```

realiza o login e senha com os atributos que foram adicionados no `login_data` e depois imprimir a página.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: A forma correta de autenticação depende de cada site. Não é porque o seu código funcionou em um site que vai funcionar no outro. Você deve analisar o site que quer se autenticar por meio das ferramentas de desenvolvedor dos navegadores (F12 no Chrome), avaliando requisições, respostas, cabeçalhos, etc. Eu tentei por algum tempo destrinchar a lógica de autenticação desse site e não consegui. Além disso, a variável `bs_content` não está servido para nada.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Investiguei melhor esse site e consegui me autenticar.

Em primeiro lugar, é importante notar que não existe um código padrão para autenticação em sites por meio do Requests. A autenticação entre um cliente e um servidor web é uma troca de requisições e respostas que ao final geram um token, geralmente armazenado em um cookie. Essa troca de mensagens, apesar de ter muitos pontos em comum na maioria dos sites, muitas vezes tem certas peculiaridades que só se aplicam àquele determinado site que você deseja se autenticar.

Como então descobrir a "dança" correta para se autenticar em um site via Requests? Na ausência de documentação, nos resta analisar as requisições durante uma autenticação  bem sucedida. Isso pode ser feito pelas ferramentas de desenvolvedor fornecidas pelos principais navegadores (acessadas pelo botão F12). Na seção "Rede", você consegue observar a lista de requisições feitas pelo navegador. Você também pode usar o [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) para fazer essa captura.

Analisando especificamente o site que você quer se autenticar, observa-se que são necessárias duas requisições:

- GET https://shopper.com.br/shpprtkn: essa requisição retorna alguns cookies necessários para a autenticação e também um token CSRF.
- POST https://shopper.com.br/login: essa é a requisição da autenticação propriamente dita, onde o usuário e senha são enviados ao servidor.

Para tornar a requisição o mais fiel possível da que ocorre no navegador, recomendo que copie todos os cabeçalhos usados nessas requisições (nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor do Chrome, isso pode ser feito com botão direito na requisição > Copy > Copy request headers). Muitos desses cabeçalhos não são de fato necessários para uma autenticação bem sucedida, mas começar por onde sabemos que está funcionando é um bom ponto de partida.

Finalmente, após análise das requisições e cópia dos cabeçalhos, temos o seguinte código:

```
from requests import Session

login_data = {
    "email": "user@email.com",  # Substitua pelo seu email
    "senha": "password",  # Substitua pela sua senha
    "method": "sms",
}


with Session() as s:
    headers = {
        "Host": "shopper.com.br",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "sec-ch-ua": '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google Chrome";v="98"',
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36",
        "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"Windows"',
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Origin": "https://landing.shopper.com.br",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
        "Referer": "https://landing.shopper.com.br/",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    }
    r = s.get("https://shopper.com.br/shpprtkn", headers=headers)

    headers = {
        "Host": "shopper.com.br",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Content-Length": "90",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "sec-ch-ua": '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google Chrome";v="98"',
        "X-CSRFToken": s.cookies["csrftoken"], # Token obtido pela requisição anterior
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36",
        "sec-ch-ua-platform": '"Windows"',
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Origin": "https://landing.shopper.com.br",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
        "Referer": "https://landing.shopper.com.br/",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    }
    r = s.post("https://shopper.com.br/login", headers=headers, data=login_data)
    home_page = s.get("https://shopper.com.br/lojas/")
    print(home_page.text)
```

Note que:

1. O fato de haver um popup não tem nenhuma influência.
2. Pelo menos no trecho de código que consta na pergunta, `bs_content` não tem nenhuma função.
3. Esse site faz uso intenso de JavaScript. É possível que as informações que você deseja obter não estejam acessíveis prontamente na página HTML "crua" que o Requests retorna (o Requests **não** executa JS). Se esse for o caso, você terá que continuar analisando as requisições para encontrar qual é a responsável por retornar os dados de interesse, ou então utilizar uma alternativa que seja capaz de executar JavaScript (por exemplo, [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)).